# Cookie is set in my browser, not in my php-script

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to add a popup div to a wordpress page, I am trying to achieve this by having a div popup using the header.php file in my wordpress theme, it works like a charm on my webpage;
ht tp://78.69.194.141/ wordpress/?p=11

But when I try to get the script working on my live webpage it does not work.

The script works like this;
if the user presses the cross on the div, a cookie gets set, whenever header.php gets loaded, my php script checks if the cookie is set, is it then don't show the popup.

Here is how the script for the div looks;
htt p://pastebin.com/GJP8ZmC9

And the setcookie.php;
http://pastebin.com/ZcrLR2vy

As you can see, I check if the mepopp value exist, then don't show the div, and here is what it looks like in my browser;
http://cdn.imghack.se/images/dd83c239c75394659955839f45764d64.png

The problem is somewhat illogical to me and it's about $_COOKIE['mepopp'] is not set in my php code, but in my browser it is set?

What could possibly be causing this?

//Henric Johansson

Comment: Exactly when is the PHP script executed? Before or after the user clicks on the add-a-cookie button?

Comment: By default cookie is set to the same path as the script executed. If you use SEO urls for example, this can cause problems. So always set the $path of the cookie to '/'

Comment: It is executed using Ajax after he clicks on it.
It works on some pages, but on some pages the popup shows up... very strange problem. Darhazer; I have it set to '/', updated first post with script.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie doesn't show up in $_COOKIES until the next page load, could this be the case here?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: It works for 4~ posts, then almost always on the 5th post or more the check doesn't work.

Comment: The link to setcookie.php isn't working, I'd love to check it out :)

Comment: I tried out the site you linked to at 78.69.194.141 and I noticed the expiry date for the cookie ("Popup_Done", I guess it changed name?) set to the current time. Is that due to devtesting or might that be an actual problem?

Comment: It was for testing, the problem is not on my server, it works fine there, it's on the other server it's not working..

Comment: Is the other server available for testing so I can try it out for myself and actually see problem in action?